Join tables from different locations in dataform
Is there any possibility to join two tables from BigQuery using dataform if the first table is stored in US location and the second one is in EU location? Is dataform able to do any data transfers through different locations?
My task is to make some transformations on the data and keep them in new dataset. The problem is the crucial table with additional info I need for the transformation is stored only in a separate table in EU.

The way I think of the problem is "Can I solve this without Dataform?".   For example, if I have table "A" in one region and table "B" in another region, can I perform a JOIN on the two?   My understanding is "no". BigQuery requires that the data to be joined must both be in the same BigQuery region.
Dataform adds management to the SQL statements you want to execute.  Think of Dataform as a SQL generator/compiler.  If the resulting SQL won't function then Dataform isn't going to solve the puzzle.
For your overall puzzle, you need to bring one of the tables you are joing on to just one region.  Dataform will let you execute arbitrary SQL ... so you could perform an table copy from one region to another and then do a join on both tables as long as they are in the same region.
